# Desktop Windows Application automation using winium using c#

Tags: c#, windows, automation, desktop

If multiple elements have got the same name and there is no unique id for elements?How do we proceed automation using winium ?

Is it possible to use clickable point coordinates for automation? If possible how to do it?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to  Stackoverflow. Please take a moment to read the help center- https://stackoverflow.com/help/

Answer (score 1):

sometimes elements dont have **unique ID** available , but they have a unique **automation ID** which is helpful while automating the process

Comment: yeah but unable to find automation id for elements even after adding automation id  in the code.